# Perl tcp_proxy for http

Tags: perl, tcp, proxy, http-headers

Good day! I'm not very good at writing Perl, but there is a terrible need.
I found a complete solution for the organization as it reverse proxy ...

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use warnings;
use strict;

use IO::Socket::INET;
use IO::Select;

my @allowed_ips = ('all');
my $ioset = IO::Select->new;
my %socket_map;

my $debug = 1;

sub new_conn {

    my ($host, $port) = @_;
    return IO::Socket::INET->new(
        PeerAddr => $host,
        PeerPort => $port
    ) || die "Unable to connect to $host:$port: $!";
}

sub new_server {
    my ($host, $port) = @_;

    my $server = IO::Socket::INET->new(
        LocalAddr => $host,
        LocalPort => $port,
        ReuseAddr => 1,
        Listen    => 100
    ) || die "Unable to listen on $host:$port: $!";
}

sub new_connection {
    my $server      = shift;
    my $remote_host = shift;
    my $remote_port = shift;

    my $client    = $server->accept;
    my $client_ip = client_ip($client);

    unless (client_allowed($client)) {

        print "Connection from $client_ip denied.\n" if $debug;
        $client->close;
        return;
    }
    print "Connection from $client_ip accepted.\n" if $debug;

    my $remote = new_conn($remote_host, $remote_port);
    $ioset->add($client);
    $ioset->add($remote);

    $socket_map{$client} = $remote;
    $socket_map{$remote} = $client;
}

sub close_connection {
    my $client = shift;

    my $client_ip = client_ip($client);
    my $remote    = $socket_map{$client};

    $ioset->remove($client);
    $ioset->remove($remote);

    delete $socket_map{$client};
    delete $socket_map{$remote};

    $client->close;
    $remote->close;

    print "Connection from $client_ip closed.\n" if $debug;
}

sub client_ip {
    my $client = shift;

    return inet_ntoa($client->sockaddr);
}

sub client_allowed {
    my $client = shift;

    my $client_ip = client_ip($client);
    return grep { $_ eq $client_ip || $_ eq 'all' } @allowed_ips;
}

die "Usage: $0 <local port> <remote_host:remote_port>" unless @ARGV == 2;

my $local_port = shift;
my ($remote_host, $remote_port) = split ':', shift();


print "Starting a server on 0.0.0.0:$local_port\n";
my $server = new_server('0.0.0.0', $local_port);
$ioset->add($server);

while (1) {

    for my $socket ($ioset->can_read) {

        if ($socket == $server) {

            new_connection($server, $remote_host, $remote_port);
        }
        else {

            next unless exists $socket_map{$socket};
            my $remote = $socket_map{$socket};
            my $buffer;
            my $read = $socket->sysread($buffer, 4096);

            if ($read) {

                $remote->syswrite($buffer);
            }
            else {

                close_connection($socket);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine, but the web server to which I redirect the client does not see HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR and HTTP_X_REAL_IP. The lower the standard modules, the better.
I would be grateful for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not see it. Because you make TCP-redirection, not HTTP-redirection, and the proxy adds no new headers. You need to make redirection at the HTTP-level if you want to get this fields.